# ES6 generators - Not all breakpoints in Chrome Debugger are available

Tags: javascript, webpack, generator, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga & generators.
It's seems I cannot stop on breakpoint in chrome debugger since they are not available.
Setting breakpoints in specific lines make them jump to a different line...
In Addition step into leads not to the body of the function but to its header.

Source map configuration:

```
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
```

Animation showing what I mean:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not the same, but you can try adding `debugger;` into your code to add breakpoints wherever you want.

Comment: @IvánPérez thanks, but its not the developer experience I want

Comment: You could wonder about the line where you *spread*, but it makes sense that you cannot put a break on a line with only a comment or a closing brace of an object literal. These lines do not represent executable code.

Comment: Added gif @trincot

Comment: I had this same problem, and noticed that in the newest Firefox release (71) it does not have this problem! And actually I'm very impressed with FF's dev tools. Not really a solution but maybe give FF a shot?